# Product key javascript regex going haywire

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am making a [Windows Vista simulator](https://james.douglastechnology.co.uk/projects/simulator/windowsVista/test.html), and am currently trying to make the product key activation sreen. I am using JavaScript and regex to format the text value of the input to achive an uppercase set of five groups of five characters seporated by dashes, which I am trying to achive with the following code:

```js
$('#input-product-key').on('input', function() {
  if (!!$(this).val()) { var text = $(this).val().replace('-','').toString().toUpperCase().match(/.{1,5}/g).join("-"); $(this).val(text); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-product-key" maxlength="25">
```

However, after the 12th character is added to the box, dashes get added where they shouldn't be more and more, and also pressing backspace adds more dashes. Why is this?

Comment: Just FYI but you dont need to use jQuery to get/set the value. You can just use `this.value`

Comment: @JamesDouglas while that is usually true, performing `$(this).val()` is performing an object instantiation through a method call, and then a following method call, all doing the same thing that `this.value` does with direct property access, with much less over head.  While jQuery is useful, you should be aware of the over head you are injecting into your application(s).

Comment: @JamesDouglas jQuery is not an all-or-nothing. It is a library to help make working with the DOM easier. You should not shoehorn it into every little bit of code. If you already had a jQuery object using `.val()` is fine but to create a jQuery object JUST to pull the value from an HTMLInputElement is silly and pointless. And it WILL make life harder for you.

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace the first `.replace('-', '')` by this `replace`:

```
.replace(/-/g,'')
```

Since the prior will only replace the first `-`; the `g` flag will make sure that with the latter one every dash is replaced.

```js
$('#input-product-key').on('input', function() {
  if (!!$(this).val()) { var text = $(this).val().replace(/-/g,'').toString().toUpperCase().match(/.{1,5}/g).join("-"); $(this).val(text); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-product-key" maxlength="29" style="width:50%">
```

Comment: I'd like to also replace every _replace_ by a **replace** but with the format `replace`d each time...

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up for me. I've noticed I will now need to replace `maxlength="25"` with `maxlength="29"` to compensate for the dashes. Why doesn`t the original code count the dashes in the `maxlength`?

Comment: The length seems to be all over the place, in your example it can go as high as 28 for some reason